# NSStrings' not equal even though characters are the same

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm retrieving a string from an NSData object dataOut (coming from a CBCharacteristic), and defining a testString as well which is defined as the same value as shown below:
[image]

The problem is when I try to compare the two, I get that the two strings are not equal, even though the debugger shows otherwise:

[image]

Here is the comparison:

[image]

The log keeps logging "Strings are not equal!"

What am I doing wrong? Is the encoding incorrect, even though the strings are the same?

Comment: try make them NSData and print the data

Comment: ah you are right...there is overhead in the NSData -- one is 20 bytes vs the other being 10 byes...

Comment: dataoutString: <54467139 4c48426e 6f610000 00000000 00000000> testString: <54467139 4c48426e 6f61>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will see them are different when you convert them to `NSData` and print out the data.

What you see is not always what you get especially with Unicode characters. There maybe invisible characters or some characters that looks similar.